# I cannot figure out Uncompilable source code - variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables, exception

I'm new to learning Java and am writing a BMI Calculator program. I've fixed so many errors in my program but just cannot figure this one out! Hopefully, you can help and it will be the last error I need to fix so it will finally execute without errors.

Then I can make some changes for it to do exactly what I want such as exception handling to deal with incorrect values entered etc.

I've spent so much time on this and have edited it so much that I have got myself so confused.
All feedback welcome, I'm here to learn.

This is the error I am getting on Netbeans:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
> source code - variable bmi might not have been initialized    at
> BmiCalc.main(BmiCalc.java:9)

Here is my code:

```java
{
    double bmi;
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        System.out.println("You are underweight");
    }
    else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {        
        System.out.println("You are a healthy, normal weight");
    }
```

Comment: You have multiple copies of the `bmi` variable that (other than the name itself) bear *no* relationship to each other. I suspect everything would be fine is you made it a class-level variable (i.e., just *before* the main function) rather than many function-level variables.

Comment: Thanks! I declared the variable outside of, just before the main class if that is what you mean, and I got a different error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable bmi cannot be referenced from a static context
 at BmiCalc.main(BmiCalc.java:9)

Comment: Having read your comment many times it put me in the right direction to further research class and instance variables etc. and I finally got my program to run so thank you for your reply. I ended up taking out that 'if else if' statement from the main method and putting it in to each of the other 2 methods and obviously declaring and initializing the variable in each of those 2 methods. I'm not sure if it's 'good' coding but it worked so thanks for your input. I'm new here so not sure if I should post my edited code or should I replace the code above with it?

Comment: Julie, had you got an answer, I'd leave the code as is since it was the code you were having troubles with (nobody wants to see their answers invalidated, and it's relatively cheap to ask another question). Since nobody's answered yet, if you have a *different* problem, you can just edit the question to ask that one. If you now have code that works, you should probably post it in an *answer* to this question (self-answering is considered okay).